# Can I automate a Terminal Emulator with Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, terminal

Please, could you tell me if it is possible to automate Terminal Emulators using Selenium, I need it to be in Selenium not in UFT

Answer (score 2):

Possibly - if u use a terminal through a browser window.

See https://github.com/jupyter/terminado

[image]

This lets you run a terminal in a browser.
So now you might be able to get at items as web elements.
But I don't know if the terminal is displayed as part of the DOM - quite possibly not.  Whether it accepts commands like a `<input>` element remains to be seen.

So I'd try the emulator and inspect page contents and see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

NO because selenium is a browser based tool.  Browser manufacturers implement the protocol for their browsers and it works based on HTML pages.  The DOM methods wouldn't work against non-HTML windows such as a terminal.

You may wish to consider using http://sikulix.com/

*SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image recognition powered by OpenCV to identify and control GUI components. This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's internals or the source code of the application or web page you want to act on.*

Terminal windows might work quite well with this - if you set them up correctly.  possibly super small like 4 or 5 lines perhaps. Or full screen with a lot of line returns.  I think you can target a specific area though and that would be best.  The nice thing is that you don't have to worry about changes to layout and images as you would need to with HTML !

It looks like regions are used in Sikuli for areas.  **Region(x, y, w, h)**